# How would we write a C macro to insert casts into function calls?

Tags: c, casting, macros, parameter-passing, c-preprocessor

How might we write a preprocessor macro to replace every instance of:
`func(`
with
`func((DemoUnion)`?

Also, maybe a macro to replace `func((DemoUnion)(DemoUnion)` with `func((DemoUnion)`?

By the way, below is an example of how DemoUnion might be defined:

```
union DemoUnion {
    char c;
    short s;
    int i;
    float f;
}; typedef union DemoUnion DemoUnion;


// the typedef  allows us to declare instances by writing
//     DemoUnion instanceName;  
// instead of:
//     union DemoUnion instanceName;
```

Also, C allows us to cast to union types pretty easily:
(so long as the input to the cast is one of the types included in the union)

```
int main() {
  DemoUnion big = 0;
  char c  = 1;
  big = (DemoUnion) c; // cast char to union type

  func(big);
  func((DemoUnion) c);
}
```

Comment: Have you considered the option of *using the proper types* ?

Comment: The compiler does not know what to do with `big = (DemoUnion) c;` so I suggest `big.c = c;`

Comment: "C allows us to cast to union types pretty easily" No C does not, gcc does.

Answer (score 2):

> How might we write a preprocessor macro to replace every instance of:
>
> ```
> func(
> ```
>
> with
>
> ```
> func((DemoUnion)?
> ```

We wouldn't write such a macro, because C does not afford a way to do it.  Macro expansion replaces the macro identifier and, for function-like macros, its argument list, with the macro's replacement text.  The `(` character cannot be part of a macro identifier, and it is not, by itself, an argument list.  Thus, `func(` is not a unit that is subject to macro expansion.

You could, however, do this:

```
#define func(x) func((DemoUnion)(x))
```

That will have about the effect you describe, but it is specific to argument-list length.  Also, you do not have to worry about recursive expansion; C specifies that it does not happen.

> Also, maybe a macro to replace `func((DemoUnion)(DemoUnion)` with
>   `func((DemoUnion)`

Nope.  Macro replacement replaces *macros*, not general text patterns.  Anyway, anywhere that a `(DemoUnion)` cast is valid, `(DemoUnion)(DemoUnion)` is also valid and equivalent.

But note well that you have a serious misconception:

> Also, C allows us to cast to union types pretty easily: (so long as
>   the input to the cast is one of the types included in the union)

On the contrary, **C *does not* allow casting to or from union types**.  At all.  Some compilers will accept such casts as an extension, but it is non-standard.  The closest the (C2011) standard permits would involve using a compound literal:

```
DemoUnion u = (DemoUnion) { .c = c };
```

Note well that although part of the syntax for a compound literal resembles a cast operator, there is no cast there.  But really, why do that, when you can just use an ordinary initializer:

```
DemoUnion u = { .c = c };
```

... or ordinary member assignment:

```
DemoUnion u;
u.c = c;
```

as the situation warrants.

Going the other way, of course, you should just use member selection:

```
char c2 = u.c;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have define name with "(". However, you may use function macro:

```
#define FOO(X) FOO((DemoUnion) (X))
```

or with variable number of arguments:

```
#define FOO(...) FOO((DemoUnion) __VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: There's not much point to a variadic macro, since you must know how many actual arguments function `FOO()` takes anyway.  As for your non-variadic example, do be careful.  Consider what it would do to `FOO(c - '0')`, for instance, in light of operator precedence.

Comment: Thx, good point with macro variable brackets. Variadic version is only for the first of argument - but have the same problem pointed out. It is possible to make an EVAL() macro to do this for every argument, but this looks hacky.